# polymorphism with Windows Forms

Tags: c#, polymorphism

I'm making a project to get myself more familiar with Windows Forms and Graphic User Interfaces.

I have created this program for the Department of Motor Vehicles that uses polymorphism in CONSOLE. So when I input a taxi, it will call the base class of an industrial vehicle rather than a personal vehicle.

The program works fine in console.

But I'm wondering if that's implementable through a Graphical Interface. I know I can just have buttons with the types of vehicles, then have a new form open up to input that data for that specific type of vehicle. But that wouldn't be polymorphism....

Is this a type of project that could be done with polymorphism? and GUI's or no?

Comment: No reason it couldn't be done. You might need to provide some code or more details on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Are you asking about using abstract classes? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5(v=vs.71).aspx
Can you paste the code you have created that uses polymorphism in CONSOLE?

Comment: Typically, having a view for each model is a good way to go. Having different sub-views for related portions of the model (such as a manufacturer information view) allows for ***composition*** of the views, rather than *inheritance*.

Comment: I have 10 different classes, the pasting of code isnt an option. I know I can just select a vehicle type and have it create the number of textbox input fields I need to input the data, but that wouldn't be Polymorphism... I'm beginning to think it's not doable with polymorphism

Comment: If you have any kind of user interface - graphical or console - to manage your data, and you have designed your data independently of the UI, then I expect you to encounter the same problems with both solutions concerning polymorphism. But who can say without seeing any code examples?

Answer (score 1):

I think you would get more bang for the buck if only one form was created which handled the base class as mentioned. But it would turn on/off or make visible items as required by the derived classes. The GUI doesn't have to be polymorphic, it just needs to handle the polymorphism of the data. HTH

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to be more specific about what you want to achieve. Polymorphism can be applied to most problems, if you like. Whether or not it's a **good** technique varies, and depends very much on how you use it. You seem to be forming ideas about how your object hierarchy will work early on, whereas I would suggest that you **don't** start there - instead specify what your application should **do** and how it should do it, and design your object model around that. It may turn out that your idea of how to represent (given your example) a taxi actually isn't useful.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason why you can't benefit from polymorphism in any object-oriented application, regardless of what user interface you elect to use. In your scenario, it may make sense to use only references to the base class in your list view, and then open up the appropriate details view suited to the specific type of the object.

Also, I recommend WPF for what it's worth. There's no use learning Windows Forms now unless you have a very good reason.

Comment: WPF lets you do nice things with matching templates to data types and you can also use reuse common elements - this would appear to cover some of the issues

Comment: As @Murph said, WPF actually can help in this situation with DataTemplates. Mainly, Windows Forms is old the old way of making Windows apps, WPF is the new way. No use learning the old way now. And, of course, WPF is better. What made you decide to use Windows Forms?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you are looking for is a way to dynamically build your GUI according to the type of (polymorphic) object you are passing? This can be done by using reflection, asking the object passed to the Form which attributes or properties it has and generate automatically input fields, text boxes etc. for each attribute.

For some examples, read this SO post:

[Dynamic options dialog (using reflection)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547867/dynamic-options-dialog-using-reflection)